# Sharepoint 2010 InfoPath form validation

Tags: 2010, infopath, infopath-rules

I need to set validation in Sharepoint 2010 Infopath form single line text box as field only allows 5 Alpha and Numeric character types.

For limiting char I followed below step.

Using textbox properties -> Display ->Limit textbox to x Char

I don’t know how to allow only Alpha and Numeric char not allow all special char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for my question.

1. Open the form in InfoPath designer.
2. Click on the textbox to add a validation rule.
3. Set the condition as **Field does not match pattern**.
4. Select the custom pattern and enter **([A-Za-z0-9])*** in the custom
   pattern text box.

Reference [Click Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e6001aa-689e-4e09-b084-6b5af58581f1/infopath-texbox-validation?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)